# Avoiding Postback on button coltrol

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a user control, **reviewer.ascx** having different controls that accept values from the user. This control is placed inside a web page, **Preview.aspx**. 
There is a button control, **Preview**, in the **reviewer.ascx** control that is used to show the preview of the values provided by the user in another web page, **user_preview.aspx**.
Now, the question is when this button, **Preview**, is clicked the **user_preview.aspx** page should be displayed as a popup window and the values in the **Preview.aspx(reviewer.ascs)** page should not be lost, which is currently happening because of postback.

Can anyone help me with a solution.

Comment: You could store your user values in the session : See here for example ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Then I think you shouldn't use a server-side control, but a simple HTML link with some javascript.

You can use Window.open(url, title, args) to open something in a pop-up window.